# Does it makes sense to use Silverlight and ajax in the same web page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, silverlight

I would like to build a client side form of user information. Can I use for validation both technologies as Silverlight and ajax? Does it not infects each other in any way? What about javascript? Can I use all technologies on one page or its better to choose just one of them.
Working with asp.net mvc.

Comment: It's best to avoid SilverLight unless your website is targeting IE/Windows only. You are better of using Ajax/Javascript.

Comment: @Raynos: while I agree sticking with Ajax/Javascript is better than using Silverlight, I want to point out that Silverlight runs in all the major browsers on all major platforms.

Comment: @Fretje Are you suggesting MoonLight is stable and usable? Besides I hate installing 3rd party extensions to my browser for trivial stuff. This kind of Microsoft technology was built for MicroSoft/IE. Even Flash is a nightmare in Linux.

Comment: @Raynos: So that means you don't run Flash in your browser either? I don't know how's the situation with the stability of MoonLight, but I can assure you that Silverlight runs smooth in Chrome and in Firefox (on windows that is). So while you might be right about the fact that it was built for Windows, you're definitely wrong about it being IE only.

Comment: @fretje Yes it does run in Firefox/Chrome. I never said it was IE only. I still wouldn't use SilverLight if I wanted to target those browsers and I defiantly do not trust SilverLight to work smoothly on mac/linux.

Comment: @Raynos: Errm... read your first comment... last word... I might have misinterpreted it though.

Comment: Silverlight is supported by MS on every major browsers for Windows AND MacOS (not powerPC however). Mac isn't the problem.

Comment: @fretje probably should put a disclaimer on it with it being my opinion. Yes silverlight can be used cross browser but I would avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can use whatever you want together.

---

In my opinion it is good to use HTML5/javascript (webSocket. .. instead of Ajax) and forget about Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense.
You're comparing apples and oranges... Silverlight is a whole user interface technology,  (and asp.net mvc is as well) but Ajax is only a small subset of a user interface technology. You can use ajax to do calls in an mvc application (or any other UI framework based on html), but Silverlight provides an api to do calls to the server (it's technically almost the same as ajax, but it isn't called ajax).

So when you build your client side form using an mvc view (so using html in the end), you can use ajax to do your (client side) validation. This is not required, as the validation should also happen on the server.
When you use Silverlight to build your client side form, you use the methods built into Silverlight to do your validation. This is also client validation (as Silverlight is a "client side" technology). When your Silverlight application posts data back to the server (using a technology built into Silverlight, probably WCF), your server side "services" should also validate the input!

I see one option where you'd want to use Silverlight inside an asp.net mvc application: for example when you would want to display a media player based on Silverlight (to embed a movie in a web page for example). Just like you would with Flash when you embed a YouTube movie on a page.

Comment: preferably recommend the HTML5 video API instead of SilverLight/Flash.

Comment: @Raynos: sure, but it's an example of where you would mix Silverlight with asp.net mvc... Also, if your video is on a specific website, you have to use the tools they provide. I don't know if it's already possible to embed a YouTube video using the HTML5 API, but otherwise you don't have a choice, you have to use what they use (Flash in this case).

Comment: And there are simply things not doable with HTML5 now: Smooth streaming technologies comes to mind, or content over video. Technology is not religion, use what is best considering your requirements, abilities etc...